# How to deal with "Please follow us on <social-media>"?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

I just came across an answer thats ends with:

> Hope you like it. Please follow us on **Telegram** and **Instagram**

<sub>Removed the links so they won't get any clicks</sub>
<sub>[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y59NS.png)</sub>

---

How should I deal with requests like this one?

Should I:

1. Just edit it out
2. Flag as 'spam', even tho the rest of the answer is fine
3. Flag for moderator intervention and provide the above reason?

Comment: 1. Just edit it out (more details in linked faq)

Comment: If the promotion is repeated even after the OP has received warnings in comments, probably escalate by flagging as spam.

Comment: For me, it's spam: show no mercy... (and please subscribe instead to my XXXXX account.... :D). More seriously, it should not be a place to advertize people's own accounts on social media. I don't mind that they link their social media in their profile's bio, but never ever in questions or answers.

Comment: I've removed the text from 4 of his answers. I'll keep an eye on the user and flag for a mod if they keep appearing.

Comment: If it's a good quality answer, just edit and leave a comment to let them know they can put that sort of thing in the profile. If bad answer - just a vehicle for the link, then spam.